# Matplotlib : Set default value for plt.axis to "equal"

Tags: matplotlib

I have many plots to draw and I wish to see all of them with the option plt.axis("equal").
Is there a way to fix Matplotlib default settings to plt.axis("equal") (as what is proposed by matplotlib.rcParams for most of the Matplolib paramaters) ?
Thanks,
Patrick

Answer (score 0):

I have created an [issue / feature request (8088)](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/8088) for this.

As it was pointed out there this `rcParams` doesn't work for pyplot.plot() yet. Hopefully it will be implemented soon.

However, the following works already and is the solution in case of images:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams['image.aspect'] = 'equal'
a=[[1],[2]]
plt.imshow(a)
```